# Similarities and differences between Scala macros and C++ templates

Tags: c++, templates, scala, macros

Scala's Macros and C++ templates both provide access to compile time meta-programming. Could you elaborate on similarities and differences? Are they equal in terms of expressiveness?

Comment: It is not at all difficult to tell what is being asked. Please read and think before you click close.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One important difference between them is that Scala macros are written in Scala, whereas C++ templates are their own programming language, which is completely unlike C++. C++ is an imperative object-oriented strict impure language, C++ templates are a declarative hybrid logic/functional non-strict pure language, which was never intended to be used as a full-fledged programming language, and thus lacks many of the features necessary for programming in the large.

Comment: I agree with much of the answer, except the object-oriented tidbit. C++ is multi-paradigms, it takes a bit from OO, but Alan Kay would have fits if it was the OO model, and on the other hand it offers much more than what OO traditionally offers.

Answer (score 4):

They both provide compile time metaprogramming and both are turing complete, but that's about all they have in common. I am no expert on C++, but as far as I know, the fact that C++ templates are turing complete is rarely exploited and using them for actual programming is hard. Often, templates are just used to provide parametric polymorphism (aka generics), whereas Scala macros are written in Scala and can use the full power of the language at compile time.

Comment: It's true that C++ templates are hard-ish to use for actual programming -- the obvious numpty examples like computing a factorial are easy but not very useful. Some thing have been made easier by Boost and C++11, for example a bunch more built-in type traits, and tools like `enable_if`. C++11 also introduces `constexpr`, which is a completely separate tool for compile-time computation. I would say that the common use of templates in C++ is for compile-time computations *operating on types*. Anything beyond that is rare/difficult/arcane.

Comment: The fact that they are turing complete is rarely exploited, but the templates themselves are often exploited. On the other hand, the facilities usable at compile-time are quite limited, even with the advent of `decltype` and `constexpr`. I don't know what are the restrictions in Scala, can you *print* (to the screen at least) ?

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Scala Macros are written in Scala. You can do everything at compile time you can do at runtime. There are no restrictions. (Well, the compiler has some timeout and memory caps, which are intended to thwart runaway macros, but that's about it.)

Comment: There are no restrictions in Scala. There are even macros that access a database at compile time.

Comment: @SteveJessop: comments aren't meant for asking separate questions. And no.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Wow, that poses some constraints on the compiler!